# How can I map each value found into a different variable

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I want to create a chef recipe and I'm stuck at this step:

```
members = search("node", "recipe:redis AND chef_environment:#{node.chef_environment}") || []
members.each do |node|
  puts "#{node["ipaddress"]}"
end
```

This is working and returning me the IP addresses for those three servers found.
But I want to assign/give each VALUE found (ip address) to a variable because I will run a command like the following:

```
execute 'command' do
  command "redis-trib.rb create --replicas 1 #{node1}:6379 #{node2}:6379 #{node3}:6379 #{node1}:6380 #{node2}:6380 #{node3}:6380"
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
nodes = members.map do |node|
          node["ipaddress"]
        end
```

And then use it like this:

```
execute 'command' do
  command "redis-trib.rb create --replicas 1 #{nodes[0]}:6379 #{nodes[1]}:6379 #{nodes[2]}:6379 #{nodes[0]}:6380 #{nodes[1]}:6380 #{nodes[2]}:6380"
end
```